# naming properties in application context xml file

Tags: spring

I want to inject some objects in my web application using spring dependency injection.

In `EtudiantServiceImpl` class I have :

```
@Autowired
private IEtudiantDao etudiantDao;
```

And in `EtudiantAction` class I have :

```
@Autowired
private EtudiantServiceImpl etudiantService;
@Autowired
public Etudiant etudiant;
```

And in my application context xml file I have this :

```
<bean name="etudiantAction" class="tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction" scope="prototype">
         <property name="etudiantService">
            <ref bean="etudiantService"/>
         </property>
         <property name="etudiant" class="tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.domain.Etudiant">
         </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="etudiantService" class="tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl">
        <property name="etudiantDao" class="tp.ihm.gestionEtudiant.dao.EtudiantDaoImpl">
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But I'm getting an error in the xml file saying :

```
Attribute : name
The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions.

Data Type : string
```

for : `<property name="etudiantService">` and `name="etudiant"` and `<property name="etudiantDao"`.

How can I solve that ?

Comment: The `property` tag doesn't have an attribute `class`. You can specify `ref` or `value`. Also you should use the interface `EtudiantDao` and `EtudiantService` in your classes not the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to define it in XML file if you define it as "AutoWired". Just annotate EtudiantAction as @Controller

```
@Controller
class EtudiantAction{

... Same as your code
}
```

Same thing for EtudiantServiceImpl, annotate as @Service

Now you can remove entire from context xml